# Provide a SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE (long unsigned int) as said by MSDN, function expects HANDLE (void*)

Tags: c++, windows, service

I'm trying to create a service that detects USB being plugged in. In order to do so, I have to create a `HDEVNOTIFY` via `RegisterDeviceNotification(HANDLE, LPVOID, DWORD)`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx), about the the first argument:

> A handle to the window or service that will receive device events for the devices specified in the NotificationFilter parameter. The same window handle can be used in multiple calls to RegisterDeviceNotification.
>
> Services can specify either a window handle or **service status handle**.

So I did this (`svcStatHandle` is a `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE`):

```
hDeviceNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification( svcStatHandle,          
                                            &NotificationFilter,
                                            DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
```

But g++ gave the following error when compiling:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE {aka long unsigned int}' to 'HANDLE {aka void*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Based on that, I conclude that by the code I try to provide a `long unsigned int` (a value) where a `void*` (a pointer) is expected.

Several frustrating hours later, after the error first came out, I successfully get it working by adding `-fpermissive` to the compiler command line flag (It turns into a warning), but *I'd like to know exactly what is going wrong here*. Providing a value where a pointer is expected doesn't sound right, and I'd like to keep my code clear from warnings.

Comment: "I successfully get it working by adding -fpermissive" no you didn't, you only made compiler shut up. If you are sure that `svcStatHandle` is a correct handle then you may need to perform a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: really `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is pointer to some type (`typedef struct {int unused;} *SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;`) so must be compatible with `void*` pointer, converted without explicit cast and warnings. from where you got your definition - `'SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE {aka long unsigned int}'` ?

Comment: @VTT Well that makes sense, but I said that because since`RegisterDeviceNotification` gives no error, I assumed that all the args are OK.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using some g++ winapi headers instead of Windows SDK? They may have those "little differences"

Comment: `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` is not `long unsigned int` - this error in definition.

Comment: @RbMm It's from the compiler error message. I also tought that it *has* to be compatible somehow..

Comment: *It's from the compiler error message.* - must not be `long unsigned int` - this mean you use incorrect definition of `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` - you need look where and how it defined

Comment: @VTT That's a point.  So where can I compare those "little difference"?

Comment: I located this definition in `winsvc.h`: `typedef DWORD SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;`

Comment: `typedef DWORD SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;` - this is wrong definition. from which sdk version this  `winsvc.h`?! however in any sdk can not be so

Comment: why you not use standard sdk/wdk from microsoft ?

Comment: @RbMm This one's from MinGW. I use it, yah, because that's the one already in my machine. Would you suggest directly editing that definition in the header file?

Comment: i suggest use standard sdl/wdk headers. you can of course edit this headers to `typedef PVOID SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;` or something like this, but possible here exists and another errors. the `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` us pointer, so 64bit value in 64bit code. the `typedef DWORD SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE;` definitelly can cause random runtime crash in 64bit code

Comment: @RbMm WDK does not seem to have `winsvc.h`, let alone `windows.h`. Directly editing the header already available works best for me. Please add that as an answer, so I can mark it accepted.

Comment: `winsvc.h` is part of any windows *SDK*

Comment: mingw-w64 declares this properly in its version of [winsvc.h](https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/blob/v5.x/mingw-w64-headers/include/winsvc.h#L137). Are you using an ancient version of MinGW? You won't be able to use all headers in the SDK without editing them due to incompatibilities between VC++ and gcc/g++. That's why MinGW has its own copy.

Comment: I found the incorrect definition in the [original MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/5.0-active/tree/w32api/include/winsvc.h#l165) project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `winsvc.h` header file is found out to have an incorrect definition, as shown on the [original MinGW project](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/5.0-active/tree/w32api/include/winsvc.h#l165) (pointed out by eryksun), so it's probably an outdated version as according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64), [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) has been built in order to support 64bit and new APIs. Most importantly it contains the correct definition for `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE`. Makes a lot of sense since I got my MinGW from that outdated source.

This means replacing with MinGW-w64 is the best way to go in the long run, but directly editing `winsvc.h` also worked albeit the possibility of side-effect